# It is Possible to change admin base url main site to secondary website?

Tags: magento2, admin

I have multi-website in `Magento 2.3.1`. So the main site has an admin URL like "/admin". But I want to change the admin URL to my secondary website.

For instance,
**From** > [www.mainsite.com/admin](http://www.mainsite.com/admin) **To** > [www.secondsite.com/admin](http://www.secondsite.com/admin)

Also I checked `store > configuration  > Admin > Custom Admin Url`

But it is not working.

Any suggestion?